# c++, JSON, get object members in an array

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I am using `nlohmann::json` for parsing json in the program.

given a json there is an array with several objects, according to one of the object members I want to get other members of the same object.

like in the json below

```
{
 "arr":[
    {"a":1, "b":11, "c":111, ...},
    {"a":2, "b":22, "c":222, ...},
    {"a":3, "b":33, "c":333, ...},
    ...
   ]
}
```

for instance if the value of `a` is `2`, I want to get the values of b,c,... of the same index/object.

currently I am using a for loop and at the index that `j["arr"][i]["a"].get<int> == 2` going for the rest of members. As the array might have hundreds of members it is nonsense.

what is the best approach in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It's a JSON array, you need to iterate over it. So your approach is the simple and direct one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the C++ type of the elements of `arr` `Thing`, you can convert `arr` to a `std::vector<Thing>`.

```
void to_json(nlohmann::json & j, const Thing & t) {
    j = nlohmann::json{{"a", t.a}, {"b", t.b}, {"c", t.c}}; // similarly other members ...
}

void from_json(const nlohmann::json & j, Thing & t) {
    j.at("a").get_to(t.a);
    j.at("b").get_to(t.b);
    j.at("c").get_to(t.c); // similarly other members ...
}

std::vector<Thing> things = j["arr"];
auto it = std::find_if(things.begin(), things.end(), [](const Thing & t){ return t.a ==2; });
// use it->b etc
```